# How to convert float to complex?

Tags: go, type-conversion, complex-numbers

With the very simple code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/cmplx"
)

func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return fmt.Sprint(cmplx.Sqrt(complex128(x)))
    }
    return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(sqrt(2), sqrt(-4))
}
```

I get the following error message :

```
main.go:11: cannot convert x (type float64) to type complex128
```

I tried different ways, but couldn't find out how to convert a `float64` to `complex128` (just to be able to use `cmplx.Sqrt()` function on a negative number).

Which is the correct way to handle this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't really want to convert a `float64` to `complex128` but rather you want to construct a `complex128` value where you specify the real part.

For that can use the builtin [`complex()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#complex) function:

```
func complex(r, i FloatType) ComplexType
```

Using it your `sqrt()` function:

```
func sqrt(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return fmt.Sprint(cmplx.Sqrt(complex(x, 0)))
    }
    return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/h1ADHAdvoA).

**Note:**

You can calculate the square root of a negative `float` number without using complex numbers: it will be a complex value whose real part is `0` and imaginary part is `math.Sqrt(-x)i` (so the result: `(0+math.Sqrt(-x)i)`):

```
func sqrt2(x float64) string {
    if x < 0 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("(0+%.15fi)", math.Sqrt(-x))
    }
    return fmt.Sprint(math.Sqrt(x))
}
```

Comment: Thx, you're right, that was what I was searching for.